# Ajax call to data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ajax

Client wants to direct people to a landing page. Within the landing page, there is a registration page that takes some information from the user. One of the questions is for the user to select from a time slot to attend.

This is a first-come-first-serve time slot, and only 1 person per slot. So I need to asynchronously check if the slot is open from a data extension. So is there any way to use AJAX to get to a data extension?

Comment: You mention data extensions. Is this a Marketing Cloud thing? If so, adding data extension and marketing cloud tags to the question will help direct it to the correct people.

Comment: Yes, it can be done.  Please try coding it an then update your question with some details about where you're stuck.